# Navigation Menu: Using a single centered image w/ 2 menu links on either side

Tags: nav

Ok, I'm trying to tinker with my navigation menu.  I want something like this website:

http://aleksfaure.com/

He has a single image (logo) centered with 2 menu links on either side. I've tried a couple of different things, including just using my logo as an image centered at the top, in between the menu.  No dice.

---

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS I have with my current nav menu.  I'm still kind of a intermediate beginner at this.

---

HTML

```
<nav role="navigation">

<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="#" class="mainnav">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#" class="mainnav">About Me</a></li>

<ul id="nav-right" style="float:right;">

<li><a href="#" class="mainnav">Portfolio</a></li>

<li><a href="#" class="mainnav">Contact</a></li> </ul>

</ul></nav>
```

CSS

```
#header nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 163px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#header nav ul li {
        float: left; list-style: none;
}

ul#nav li a {

    display: block; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0; 
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    font-family: 'MuseoSlab-500', Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000; 
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px #bbbaba; 
    text-decoration: none;


}
    ul#nav li a.mainnav:hover {

        color: #13cad1; 
        text-shadow: 0 2px 1px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two separate lists.  Treat the entire menu, including your image, as one list.  Consider something like this for your HTML:

```
<div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li><img src="images/yourLogo.png"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And make sure you have your

style set to float: left;

```
#nav li { float: left; list-style: none;}
```

Then, just center the entire div on the page, and style your links as you want.

SEPARATE NOTES: 
In your code, you are missing the closing tag for your first unordered list.

The navigation element is not very widely supported, so depending on your audience you may want to use a div.

Comment: this won't be perfectly centered on the middle `<li>` unless the widths of the left and right `<li>` are identical.